¿Cual de las firmas del metodo round() de la clase Math se llama al pasarle un int como parámetro?
Soy un novato que está estudiando la certificación OCP Java 11.
Tengo una duda y es que no consigo entender cual de las 2 firmas del método round() de la clase Math se llamará al pasarle un int como parámetro.
El método round() de la clase Math tiene estas firmas:
//Math.round()
long round(double num)
int round(float num)

Como cada método devuelve un tipo primitivo diferente no debería ser muy difícil averiguar cual retorna:
int num = 1;
int a = Math.round(num); //Compila bien
int b = Math.round(2.5); //COMPILE ERROR: required: int, provided: long

En resumen, se llama al método round() que tiene como parámetro float y devuelve un int pero ¿por que convierte automáticamente en float y no en double?
Hay una regla que dice que cuando un entero y un decimal se multiplican, el resultado será del tipo decimal (ya sea float o double) pero no es aplicable a este caso directamente.
¿Es posible que internamente el método round() haga multiplicaciones con mi int y por lo tanto de como resultado dicho float?
Si esto es así, ¿no debería pasar también con la otra firma de round() (la que acepta un double)?
Me gustaría entenderlo bien porque seguro que es una duda relativamente común dentro de la certificación.
Es mi primera vez preguntando en el foro, espero haberme explicado bien :)
Gracias por la ayuda!!

Como puedes ver en el tutorial oficial para float se le agrega el prefijo f a los números
// entero 26 base 10 (decimal)
int decVal = 26;
//  entero 26, en hexadecimal
int hexVal = 0x1a;
// entero 26, en binario
int binVal = 0b11010;
//para doble no se agrega ningún prefijo
double d1 = 123.4;
// la notación científica se coma como doble
double d2 = 1.234e2;
// los flotantes llevan el prefijo f
float f1  = 123.4f;
//desde java 7 ya se pueden usar guines bajos para mejorar la legibilidad
float pi =  3.14_15F;

ahora ya que en tu caso no le pusiste la f, está llamando al constructor con double.
y el error que estás obteniendo es por el tipo de retorno del método round cuando le pasas un double es un long, no un int, como puedes ver en la documentación oficial.
¿Por qué un long?
porque el rango de valores de double es mucho mayor de lo que cabe en un int

El código que me muestras es correcto pero no tiene que ver con lo que yo pregunto.
Quizás me expresé mal, pero pregunto por que Java usa el método round() cuando le pasamos un int haciendo una promoción directa a float y no a double.
Por una parte float es el escenario más sencillo porque solo tiene que convertir en un paso (int --> float) pero double también admite valores más grandes
En mi ejemplo le paso un int, no necesito la f.
El tipo de retorno que obtengo es claramente un int porque lo puedo almacenar en la variable
Creo que no es la solución pero, gracias por tu comentario!

@Doubtman creo que deberías leer la respuesta (porque no es un comentario) de nuevo ya que si no le pones la f aún así sea 0.1 o incluso 0 es un double, no un float. Que el tipo de retorno de la función es long, así te regrese 1 será un long, no un int.
